# How to make consumer group A pick up offset of consumer group B but without affecting A's committed offset?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I created a topic **"Item"** and it has 8 partitions.

Also, I have two consumer groups A and B both are listening to this topic.
Consumer group A has offset on each of the partition.

However, I would like to set **consumer group B's** offset same as **consumer's A's offset** so that **consumer B** can start to consume messages from where **A** left without affecting A's committed offsets. Say, I have a database that store consumer A's offset and I would like B to consume from there.

Let me add a use case:
Group A is inserting messages into a table in database along with offsets. However, at some point, I copied the table to another database. But I copied a snapshot (say snapshot from 10 mins ago) of this table so some trades inserted in 
 last 10 mins are not there. In this case, I want to use Group B to populate missed trades in the copied table. So I would like Group B to set its offsets to the offsets stored on the last inserted item in that table.

Is there a way to achieve this ? Please correct me if I misunderstood something.

Comment: Will consumer A continue to consume messages after consumer B started consuming from consumer A's offsets?

Comment: Why don't you just create one cosnumer group with more consumers?

Comment: @mike A will continue to consume messages. But B shouldn't commit offset on Group A. I added a use case.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous I added a use case. More consumers won't solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could manually change the offsets of the Consumer Group B using the ConsumerGroup Command tool. You can find some information in the Kafka documentation [Managing Consumer Groups.](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_consumer_group)

If you plan to reset a particular Consumer Group ("consumerB") you can use

```sh
> bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --reset-offsets --group consumerB --topic Item --to-latest
```

There are also options available for each individual partition. That way you could set the offset to a particulat offset of consumer A.

Comment: Interesting, I will dig into this a little bit. One more thing is that since there are 8 partitions. Do I need to provide 8 offsets for each partition to Group B in order for B to pick up offsets that A inserted into database ?

Comment: Yes, offsets are for each consumer group and each topic on a partition level. So you would have to provide 8 offsets in the end.